# Is it possible for Excel to automatically put a value in a cell (A2) when a cell (A1) is selected/typed in?

Tags: excel, vba, xcode

I have a sheet that user complete once they have arranged for a document to be rescanned.

I intend on writing some code to send some automatic email reminders.

However what I want to happen at this stage is once someone types their name in Column A(#) i want the corresponding cell in column M (actioned) to prepopulate as a "NO".

I have searched online and there are a lot of suggestions for the IF Formula however this wont work for my sheet as when the Agent has completed their work I want column M (actioned?) to be changed to "Yes". Therefore the macro that I'll look towards writing will no longer send an email reminder to them.

Comment: thats cool, i have no formal training/background with VBA have been doing a bunch of research on it, but everything was signposting me to a formula as opposed to VBA so i was just seeing if it was going to be a possibility before plugging some hours in.

Comment: i was also going to do 2 seperate codes (eventually) one for the prepopulation of cell and then another for the email. i just wanted to one before the other sort of thing...